# Git incorporate changes from branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I need some help with getting changes from another branch without getting all the logs.

The repo looks something like this:

```
    ______ featureX
   /
---------- master
```

I have work to do for which I need all changes from the `featureX` branch.

I have `git checkout`-d the `featureX` branch and used that as a starting point to create my `featureY` branch. The repo now looks something like this:

```
           _____ featureY
    ______/      featureX
   /
----------       master
```

However, now if I push my changes and create a PR, all commits from the `featureX` branch will appear as well. Is there any way to incorporate all changes from the `featureX` branch without having it merged with `master` and *not* mess up the logs of my `featureY` branch?

Comment: Not sure but check "cherry-pick".

Comment: Rebase `featureY` on `master`, *then* your PR `featureY > master` won't bring `featureX` commits any more. But then it means you *don't* need changes from `X` in `Y`...